# Jetty running via Maven on OSX - prevent "Launcher" app from opening

Tags: java, macos, maven, jetty

We have a java app that uses an embedded jetty container.  When we start it via maven on OSX via mvn jetty:run a java app opens with the title `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`.  When it opens it steals focus from whatever is in the foreground.  Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run with

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

You could add this in MAVEN_OPTS on your Mac machine's environment (i.e., in ~/.profile or whatever your shell looks for)

Comment: This works, but for cases where a Maven plugin is forking a process (and that process is also running Maven), the settings don't seem to carry over.  I've tried putting it in both my .bash_rc and .profile but the forked process isn't picking that up.  Any ideas where else I could put it?

Comment: it's .bashrc, not .bash_rc right? I don't actually do the above. I grin and bear the annoyance. I haven't tried "fixing" it yet. My guess is perhaps the new process isn't a login shell, and you have your settings in the "interactive shell" file for your shell (bash?).. the manpage describes when .profile and when .bashrc are loaded. let me know if that helps..

Comment: any try MAVEN_OPTS not MAVEN_OPTIONS

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Prevents IntelliJ launching a separate app window when launching an application server in a run configuration. Kudos!